# react-router-dom conditional rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I want to add more code when routing path is "/flower"

So my code is below.

[App.js]

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <SideBar />
        <section>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/flower" component={Flower} />
          <Route exact path="/editorial" component={Editorial} />
        </section>
        <Footer />
      </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

[SideBar.js]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './index.css';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

class index extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <aside>
                <NavLink exact to="/" className="item"><i className="fas fa-home"></i>HOME</NavLink>
                <NavLink to="/flower" className="item"><i className="fab fa-pagelines"></i>FLOWER</NavLink>
                <NavLink to="/editorial" className="item"><i className="fas fa-newspaper"></i>EDIT</NavLink>

            </aside>
        );
    }
}
```

All page's SideBar is same except /flower.

When user entering /flower, I want to add more code to my `SideBar`.

[Not /flower]

[image]

[user entering to /flower]

[image]

But, I don't know how can I detect that current path is /flower.

Is there any solution or guideline?

Thanks.

Comment: I think I have to manipulate with props.location.pathname, But that props doesn't exist in SideBar But in Home, Flower, Edit components. So How can I access that props in SideBar or any way to manipulate it?

Comment: Why not use a `Route` in `SideBar`? Like `<Route exact path="/flower" component={SideBarFlower}/>`.

Comment: @Oblosys That is not a important thing. Can't access to pathname also.

Comment: Don't understand what you mean by 'not an important thing'. You could simply access the route props in `SideBarFlower`, but from your question it's not clear why you would need to.

Comment: @Oblosys I just want to add more sub menu, button, etc to SideBar when user only access to /flower. But currently in my code, SideBar doesn't have pathname props. So I'm confused how can I solve it.

Comment: Just put that extra stuff in a component `SideBarFlower`, wrap that in a `Route` with path `/flower` and place it in `SideBar`. The `Route` will obtain the path from the context and will only render `SideBarFlower` if it matches `/flower`, which seems to be what you want.

Comment: @Oblosys That's exactly what I want. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But, I don't know how can I detect that current path is /flower.

But you already do this with `Route` :)

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
<Route exact path="/flower" component={Flower} />
<Route exact path="/editorial" component={Editorial} />
```

You conditionally render components based on a current Path. So `Home`, `Flower` or `Editorial` will be rendered **if** current URL Path matches `path` matcher you passed to `Route`.

You can do exactly the same in Sidebar:

```
<aside>
   <NavLink exact to="/" className="item"><i className="fas fa-home"></i>HOME</NavLink>
   <NavLink to="/flower" className="item"><i className="fab fa-pagelines"></i>FLOWER</NavLink>
   <NavLink to="/editorial" className="item"><i className="fas fa-newspaper"></i>EDIT</NavLink>

   <Route 
     path="/flower" 
     render={() => (
       <div>
        <p>more stuff</p>
       </div>
     )} 
   />
</aside>
```

I used [render](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func) but you can use `component` prop like in other `Route`s.